# How to know if HTTP Request is a BOT

Tags: seo, user-agent, web-crawler

I am looking for a full list of User-Agents of BOTS (crawlers, spiders, twitter bots, etc).

Do you know anything?

Thanks

Comment: What does this have to do with programming?

Comment: I need it in order to filter HTTP requests

Comment: Is google down where you live? Luckily it works for me. Here you go: [http://www.user-agents.org/](http://www.user-agents.org/).

Comment: It's half a year old... anything newer?

Comment: This might be helpful: https://github.com/monperrus/crawler-user-agents

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Long story short: you can't, there's no silver bullet. Any bot could set their `user-agent` string to anything from 'googlebot' to 'spamalot'.

You can see it yourself, all you need to do is go to the first site Shinnok pointed, and start counting all those `Googlebot/2.X` bots listed in there. You block them, they change the name of the bot to random gibberish and so on. In the end you'll end up with a 10k bots list that will decrease your users load times when you try to verify if they're a bot or not.

Answer (score 4):

Check this list:
http://www.botsvsbrowsers.com/category/1/index.html

It contains a total number of 4768 bot user agents.

The other way  around to accomplishing bot detection is to use the reverse approach in a white-list way, that is, check if the user agent is not a bot, then anything else is a bot. :-)

To compile a comprehensive list of non bot user agents you can use the lists at http://www.user-agents.org/ and http://www.botsvsbrowsers.com/.

Comment: Unfortunately the links seem to not work anymore